# What data type for numbers should I choose in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql

I have a column in which various numbers should be stored. The problem is that I do not know what this number will be - `int`, or `float`. Here, for example, are possible numbers:

```
60073
75000
107.14
26.1532994
1293
```

It seemed to me that in my case the `numeric` would be the best option, because the documentation says:

> numeric   variable    user-specified precision, exact

Everything is fine when I insert an `int`, but when I insert a `float`, they increase to the maximum possible accuracy (correct, please, if I'm wrong).
Here is an example of the numbers I insert:

```
107.14
3600.0
-157.8829434
```

How they are displayed in the database:

```
107.1400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625
3600
-157.882058499999999412466422654688358306884765625
```

How is this so? I am completely confused.

I need to store the numbers the way I insert them, but they should not be strings.

If this is important, then I insert this data with the library for Python [asyncpg](https://pypi.org/project/asyncpg/), so that’s why I added the Python tag, maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store double precision floating point numbers, `double precision` is the best data type.

Comment: But how will ```int``` be stored in that case? I mean, if I insert the number ```26```, will it be in the database as ```26.0```?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I already checked - everything is written down exactly as I need. Many thanks for the help!